# Rails 4 - Complicated query between polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have a `Transaction` model, which has a polymorphic association with both `Product` and `Service`.

This are the migrations:

```
create_table :products do |t|
    t.string :name

    t.timestamps null: false
end

create_table :services do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.integer :duration

    t.timestamps null: false
end

create_table :transactions do |t|
    t.integer :amount
    t.decimal :price
    t.references :sellable, polymorphic: true, index: true
    t.references :bill, index: true, foreign_key: true

    t.timestamps null: false
end
```

This are the models

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bill
    belongs_to :sellable, polymorphic: true

    def total; price * amount; end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :transactions, as: :sellable
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :transactions, as: :sellable
end
```

Basically every transaction knows which items was sold, how many units, and how much each unit costed.

- How do I get the top 5 object, by units sold?
- How do I get the top 5 object, by units money brought-in?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the use case for custom queries/arel_table

1. Top 5 object, by units sold?
   ANS:

   SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS units FROM TRANSACTIONS GROUP BY transactions.sellable_id, transactions.sellable_type ORDER BY units desc LIMIT 5;

Please note that it would work fine in MySQL but might not work in other databases like Postgres. You need to limit the columns in SELECT clause to make it work with them

2. top 5 object, by units money brought-in

   SELECT *, SUM(amount * price) AS money_brought_in FROM TRANSACTIONS
   GROUP BY transactions.sellable_id, transactions.sellable_type
   ORDER BY money_brought_in desc
   LIMIT 5;

You can execute the raw query or using arel whichever you feel comfortable with and can then fetch the respective objects.

Just a rough idea. I hope it helps

Comment: it is not about counting rows. One Transaction could sell more than 1 unit

Comment: Then shouldn't you indicate that by a column in the transactions table as well? Sorry if I am not getting your database structure. Can you please explain how you would calculate units then?

Comment: Then first query can be modified as:
SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS units FROM TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY transactions.sellable_id, transactions.sellable_type
ORDER BY units desc
LIMIT 5;
Please note that it would work fine in MySQL but might not work in other databases like Postgres. You need to limit the columns in SELECT clause to make it work with them. Hope it helps

Comment: Because when GROUP BY is present in Postgresql, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions, since there would be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column.

Comment: Could you maybe add an example of how it would work in Postgresql, please?